# Prevent to store cache in Windows Phone 7 Browser Control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, memory, webbrowser-control

anyone know how to prevent to store cache in windows phone 7 webbrowser control? we are using browser control that display one page but whenever we open this page and go back to main page it is increase Memory, so we need to delete cache.

we have used meta tag in page for prevent Cache, but still cache is stored thays why phone memory is increase.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: It's just ie9, so it should support private browsing. Mabe it will help you.

Comment: ya but i am using browser control and there are not option available to clear cache.

Comment: Are you sure you are having issues related to the Cache, and not due to Events which are not un-subscribed?